# Razor Generator adding empty comment lines in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, razor-pages, razorgenerator

I have started using Visual Studio 2017 recently (moved from VS 2015). First thing i noticed my razore views are not compiling changes in generated files (generated cs files stay the same despite changes in cshtml files). When I tried to right click and select Run Custom Tool it showed me message which implies to install Razor Generator (which i did). Now after saving my razor view it's having lots of extra empty comment lines through out the view. Which is causing a bit of issues with final Html. Here is how that empty comments looks like:

[image]

Has anyone face this issue before? If yes please kind enough to share solution. Given the time I have, i will manually remove these extra comments as of now and will look at it later when i have more luxury of time to spend on it. Thanks in advance.